# ASP.Net MVC4 EF Model Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a simple question:

Basically, when POST submitting domain model for an update operation to a Controller Action, I would--inside the Action--call .Find() then assign values to the corresponding fields of this retrieved object and then call SaveChanges().

Now this is fine and all except when I have classes with a few dozens of fields that are updated.  I wonder if there's a shorter way and not enumerate each field in the method?

Thanks.

Comment: what about AutoMapper or ValueInjecter? It will simplify mappings of updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass your entire domain model to the view you could use that to save it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyDomainModel model) {
    db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return ....;
}
```

If you are using view models you can, for example, use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map the view model to the domain model a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not following the question correctly. But if your view is passing in an updated domain model why not just use EF to do the update instead of mapping it?

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view